# The qt framework, the main window was closed but did not exit normally

Tags: c++, qt

This is a piece of qt framework code, which is triggered after I click the button. I think that when close, qt will detect whether there is a main window (a window without a parent window) to decide whether to exit the program. When I create a new dialog object , the parent window is specified for him, that is to say, when the mainwindow is closed, there will be no main window. When there is no main window opened, qapplication will exit. Why can the program run normally?
I postponed the call of close to the back of show, and he exited successfully

```
void MainWindow::show_child() {
auto c_d = new Dialog(this);
    close();
    c_d->show();
}
```